# Two versions of glibc on the same system

Tags: c++, android, c, glibc, library-path

I currently have glibc 2.10.2 on my system. I upgraded an android installation on this same system the other day. Post the upgrade, however, I am unable to run the emulator. The emulator shuts down after posting an error which says something like: "Need glibc 2.11". My question is as follows:

Is there any way that I can use two versions of glibc on the same system at the same time?  There are some very important C/C++ programs that depend on the current installation of glibc.

Please let me know in case my question is not clear. Any help is most welcome.
Sriram.
Edit: I found some questions on stackoverflow about this issue. However, those questions were unanswered. Hoping this does not go down the same path!

Comment: Are you sure that these other programs will break if you use a newer version of glibc? (glibc is for the most part backwards compatible)

Comment: @Hasturkun: I am not sure, but I sure as hell don't want to find out..especially not the hard way!!! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the include path in your android project to v2.11 glibc path and the rest of the projects will look into the path where you have already installed version 2.10.2.

Look into the [Shared Libraries How-To in TDLP](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) and read section 3.3.1 Shared Library Names where it talks about how you can modify LD_LIBRARY_PATH to temporarily substituting a different library for a particular execution.